# javascript discriminate between iOS native uiwebview and iOS desktop webapp

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, html

I am getting all browsers or webkit info using `navigator.useragent` request. I am capable to discriminate all browsers or webkit but I get no difference between webapp (iOS desktop bookmark) and native app iOS webkit. Both throws same info string. How to discriminate them? Thank you

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. The user agent for mobile Safari is different from an iOS native app using UIWebKit, but that doesn't seem to be your question exactly.

Comment: You mean to make the difference between someone that opened the app by safari and someone that added the app to home screen and opened the bookmark?

Comment: that'i it @Mageek but discriminate app by safari between home screen is  already done, safari app contains "safari" on received string. However,  there is no difference between appto home screen and native app using webkit...

Comment: maybe it's what you want : http://www.google.com.lb/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fappcropolis.com%2Fblog%2Frunning-iphone-webapps-from-the-home-screen-only%2F&ei=QLLPT6ahHcSs8QPk48HkDA&usg=AFQjCNGWE02u1Zs-DBPOS47-nL-6JBnUtQ

Comment: I mean http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1950-Detecting-iPhone-s-App-Mode-Full-Screen-Mode-For-Web-Applications.htm

Comment: could be, will try and inform... thank you

Comment: @Mageek that's it! worked for me, please post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect if your website has been opened by the app safari, write:

```
if("standalone" in window.navigator&&!window.navigator.standalone)
```

To detect if your website has been saved to home screen and then opened, write :

```
if("standalone" in window.navigator&&window.navigator.standalone)
```